# In a pulley system, is there in instant point in time where the friction switches direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, friction, free-body-diagram

I came upon a dynamics question in Physics 20. I solved the question, but there was another question in my head that has been bugging me. This is the question below.

[image]

I solved the question with relative ease, finding that the range of the mass is between 2.8kg and 9.2kg. However, I realized that as the mass decreased, the x-component of Block A would begin dragging it down the other way, until we reach the minimum mass for Block B. Throughout this process, when does the friction switch direction (because it is always opposing the trend of motion) in that the system's trend affected by the x-component of Block A more than that of Block B? Is it a gradual change or an instantaneous switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum magnitude of the static friction force is

\begin{equation}
|\vec{F}_{s}|^{\rm (max)} = \mu_s m_A g \cos \theta = 31\ {\rm N}
\end{equation}

As $m_B$ is increased from its minimum to its maximum value, $\vec{F}_s$ will continuously change. First, the magnitude of $|\vec{F}_s|$ will be equal to the maximum value $|\vec{F}_{s}|^{\rm (max)}$, and the direction will be up the slope (in order to counter the tendency of block $A$ to fall down the slope). As $m_B$ is increased, the magnitude of $\vec{F}_s$ will decrease, until at some point it is zero. (It is an interesting exercise to work out the value of $m_B$ where the system is in equilibrium with no friction force). Then, as $m_B$ is increased further, the magnitude of $\vec{F}_s$ increases again, but this time the direction will be down the slope (this counteracts the tendency of mass $A$ to follow mass $B$ as it falls). This increase will continue until the magnitude of $\vec{F}_s$ reaches $|\vec{F}_{s}|^{\rm (max)}$. Therefore, there is no discontinuity as $m_B$ is raised from the lower end of the range you calculated, to the upper end.

When $m_B$ exceeds its bound in either direction, forcing the magnitude of $\vec{F}_s$ to go above $|\vec{F}_{s}|^{\rm (max)}|$, then something discontinuous does happen (at least in the simple freshman physics model of friction). Namely, there is a transition between static and kinetic friction, and the magnitude of the frictional force changes discontinuously.